# Limiting and Sorting with Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to learn how to use `Parse` and while it's very simple, it's also... not? Perhaps I'm just missing something, but it seems like Parse requires a lot of client-side code, and even sending multiple requests for a single request. For example, in my application I have a small photo gallery that each user has. The images are stored on Parse and obtained from parse when needed.

I want to make sure that a user can not store any more than 15 images in their gallery at a time, I also want these images to be ordered by an index.

Currently it seems like the only viable option is to perform the following steps on the client:

- Execute a query/request to get the amount of pictures stored.
- If the amount is less than 15, then execute a request to upload the picture.
- Once the picture is uploaded, execute a request that stores an object linking the user that uploaded the PFFile.

This is a total of `3` or? `6` requests just to upload a file, depending on if a "response" is considered a request by parse too. This also does not provide any way to order the pictures in the gallery. Would I have to create a custom field called "index" and set that to the number of photos received in the first query + 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worse than you think: to create the picture you must create a file, save it, then save a reference to the file in an object and save that, too.

But it's also better than you think: this sort of network usage is expected in a connected app, and some of it can be mitigated with additional logic on the server ("cloud code" in parse parlance).

First, in your app, consider a simple data model where _User has an array of images (represented, say, by an "UserImage" custom class).  If you keep this relationship as an array of pointers on user, than a user's images can be fetched eagerly, when the app starts, so you'll know the image count as a fact along with the user.  The UserImage object will have a file reference in it, so you can optionally fetch the image data and just hold the lighter metadata with the current user.

Ordering is a more ephemeral idea.  One doesn't order objects as they are saved, but rather as they are retrieved.  Queries can be ordered according to any attribute, and even more to the point, since you're retrieving all 15 images, you should consider ordering them for presentation a function of the UI, not the data.

Finally, parse limits your app not by transaction count, but by transaction rate, with a free limit low enough to serve plenty of users.

Comment: "you should consider ordering them for presentation a function of the UI, not the data." - Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question. The order in which the UI is to display the images is set by the user using a drag/drop feature in a custom implemented gallery. The first image in the gallery is used as the "profile picture" for my users. I believe I found a hack method   of creating a state for these images, however my main concern is with the client being the authoritative factor in terms of if it can upload another picture. Someone could easily modify, or use the public API to upload more than

Comment: 15 images to my application, which not only would break the design layout that I've provided, but will also just be necessary data storage being used.

Comment: If the ordering must persist, then yes, an integer can be kept as part of the data.  About security, the limit of 15 can also be enforced upon save (`beforeSave` to be exact) on the server side.

Comment: then I believe it would be more efficient to just use the local array cache for my PFUser's string of picture id's instead of querying the server for them. Chances are, unless there is an odd-ball scenario, that the client is going to have the correct pictures from the server, and in the even the client is wrong the server can decline the save anyway.